# Can this set of conditionals be simplified further?

Tags: c, math, logic

I started off with this set of conditionals:

```
if (old.tg.all && old.hg.all) {
    // reject
} 

if (new.tg.all && new.hg.all) {
    // reject
}

if (old.hg.all && new.tg.all) {
    // reject
}

if (old.tg.all && new.hg.all) {
    // reject
}

if (old.tg == new.tg) {
    if  ( (old.hg == new.hg) || (old.hg.all) || (new.hg.all) ) {
        // reject
    }
}

if (old.hg == new.hg) {
    if ( (old.tg == new.tg) || (old.tg.all) || (new.tg.all) ) {
        // reject
    }
}
```

I managed to reduce it to:

```
if (old.tg.all || new.tg.all) && (old.hg.all || new.hg.all) {
    // reject
}

if (old.tg == new.tg) {
    if  ( (old.hg == new.hg) || (old.hg.all) || (new.hg.all) ) {
        // reject
    }
}

if (old.hg == new.hg) {
    if ( (old.tg == new.tg) || (old.tg.all) || (new.tg.all) ) {
        // reject
    }
}
```

Can the number of logical operations and/or repetition of boolean conditions be reduced further?

Comment: I think this might be a better fit at math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'd recommend trying Wolfram Alpha to see if it can do such a thing for you.

Comment: What is it you want to minimize : is it the number of logical connectors ? the number of logical operations ? the length of the expression ?

Comment: If I posted the original set of C conditionals and asked if there was a way to simplify this code would it be on topic?

Comment: see edit, the question is now more clearly programming related

Answer (score 1):

### For your original question about logical expression simplification

First of all, "expression simplification" is not a well defined operation.

Second, *a* (more-or-less) standard understanding of simplifying a logical expression is [Disjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) (or, alternatively, its sibling [Conjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form)). Either may turn out simpler than both your original expression and your simplified one.

At the very least, they minimize the *depth* of the expression.

### For your completely rewritten question about C code

The main issue is *not* simplicity but *clarity* of intent with the resulting *maintainability*. You should worry not about the number of characters or lines of code you write, but about how hard it is to understand and modify the logic of the code. As long as the code is clear, a little redundancy and/or extra (cheap) checks do not hurt.

Comment: Some great points, but my question was 'Can it be simplified further?'

Comment: @Awalias: define "simplified". What I am trying to tell you is that you are asking the wrong question. There is a reason why your question was downvoted and closed.

Comment: ok, I've rephrased the question, I thought my intent would have been visible from the example "simplification". Hopefully my problem is now clear